# Activate DNS Settings for a certain reseller in Plesk

Tags: dns, web-hosting, plesk, plesk-onyx

I installed /bind, customized the DNS Template and activated DNS rights for certain Service-Plans.
Now I am able to customize DNS Settings as admin but if I change to a reseller account the settings for a specific domain are gone.

I made sure that I have selected the correct service-plan where those rights are active but still no settings for DNS for reseller accounts.

I get the following error if I try to add a new subscription and select my service-plan:

`Warning: Subscription was not synchronized with service-plan: manage_dns.`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the DNS Settings were not properly attached to the already existing resellers/subscriptions. Editing the reseller and subscribtion and save them again fixed the problem.